# Slanger: Eventmachine port exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pusher

I've installed `slanger` (and `redis`) for a rails project. Every rails instance is off.

I run `redis-server` and it works properly. But then I run:

`slanger --app_key MyPusherApiKey --secret MyPusherSecret`

and it raises the next exception:

> my-directory/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9.1/lib/eventmachine.rb:534:in `start_tcp_server': no acceptor (port is in use or requires root privileges) (RuntimeError)

```
from my-directory/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9.1/lib/eventmachine.rb:534:in `start_server'
from my-directory/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/em-websocket-0.5.1/lib/em-websocket/websocket.rb:46:in `run'
from my-directory/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/em-websocket-0.5.1/lib/em-websocket/websocket.rb:39:in `block in start'
from my-directory/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9.1/lib/eventmachine.rb:170:in `call'
from my-directory/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9.1/lib/eventmachine.rb:170:in `run'
```

I thought that if the port was in use, I could just change it like this:

`slanger --app_key MyPusherApiKey --secret MyPusherSecret -a 0.0.0.0:3646`

But I still get the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I saw that the port 8080 was being used by Nginx.
Stopped nginx and I got it working fine.

> nginx -s stop